# How do I re-scale inline org-mode images to specific widths?

Tags: image, org-mode

The following signifies a picture in org-mode that is scaled to size `width="300"`. When I preview my document in a browser, the image is successfully re-sized to 300px width; **however, when I preview the images inline using `C-c C-x C-v` (i.e., `org-toggle-inline-images`), the image is displayed but fails to be resized to width 300px**.

```
#+ATTR_HTML: width="300"
[[file:/path/to/picture.png]]
```

**Question:** How do I re-scale inline org-mode images to specific widths?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For recent versions of Org:

```
#+ATTR_HTML: :width 300
#+ATTR_ORG: :width 300
[[file:/path/to/picture.png]]
```

The syntax for  `ATTR_HTML` is the same as the other property lists.

Comment: I'll just add that for some reason I had to put the attr_org before the attr_latex (in my case) for org-mode to do the scaling. I am on Emacs 28.0.5. Perhaps it is a regession.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to have ImageMagick installed, and Emacs must be built with ImageMagick support.

Comment: Either dvipng or dvisvgm would work.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
#+ATTR_HTML: width="300"
#+ATTR_ORG: :width 300
[[file:/path/to/picture.png]]
```